# Adding to variable value on condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a variable called "total" that I would like to assign a number (or price) to and then add to that number when certain options are selected or checked. Here is the code I have so far.

Here is the code that sets the initial value (base price) of the variable that will be added to. THIS CODE CURRENTLY WORKS.

```
$('input[name=trimlevel]').change(function(){

      var total = 0;

      if(document.getElementById('basetrim').checked==true) {

              var total = 0;
              var basetrim = 3550.00;
              total = total + basetrim;
              $('#myTotal').html('$' + total);

      }else if(document.getElementById('upgrade').checked==true) {
                  var total = 0; 
              var upgrade = 2400.00;
              total = total + upgrade;
              $('#myTotal').html('$' + total);


       }else {
             $('#myTotal').html('$' + total);
           }


    });
```

Here is an example of the code used to "add to" the value of the variable.  THIS IS NOT WORKING.

```
$('input[name=leather]').change(function(){

      if(document.getElementById('leather).checked == true) {
             var leather = 180.00;
             total = total + leather;
             $('#myTotal').html('$' + total);
      }
});
```

Here is the HTML for reference

```
<div class="modelsel">
           <h2>1. SELECT MODEL</h2> <br>
           <label for="basetrim">BASE MODEL</label> 
           <input id="basetrim" type="radio" name="trimlevel" value="2400.00">
           <label for="upgrade">UPGRADED MODEL</label> 
           <input id="upgrade" type="radio" name="trimlevel" value="3550.00">

 </div>

<div class="inside">
          <h2>3. BASE MODEL ADD-ONS</h2><br>
          <input type="checkbox" value="180.00" id="leather" name="leather" />
           <label for="leather">Leather Seat (+ $180.00)</label><br>
</div>

<div id="myTotal"></div>
```

I am relatively new to Javascript and have been struggling with this for hours.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the colors of your code above, the syntax highlighting is showing you that you have syntax errors, you're missing quotes

Comment: At that point the variable `total` doesn't exist anymore so you can't add to it. You need to make it global.

Comment: Hi @Juhana! As Juhana says, total doesn't exist in your second event function. You will have to store the price information outside of both of those functions. You could also consider using the .data() jQuery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only some modifications need to be made in order to get things to work:

First one, there's a typo here:

```
if(document.getElementById('leather).checked == true) {
```

You missed a ' so substitute it by:

```
if(document.getElementById('leather').checked == true) {
```

Second, define the var `total` out of the functions and make it available to all of them. If you have your methods in the ready function you can define total there. Also remove the definition of total inside the functions or you won't use the one who is defined in ready.

Third, when the user clicks the checkbox, you're always adding value (don't know if that's what you want). In this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bLkL38L/), I add or diminish the amount of total according to the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It works perfectly now! Kinda frustrating to see it was something so simple. Thanks!

Comment: @BrandonC glad to help :) sometimes the easiest things are the toughest, please accept if it suits

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already in the comments. The context of the functions is different. You can either define total outside of the functions or use an object for your behavior.

```
var someObject = {};
```

inside your function you can write with the dot notation.

```
someObject.total = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=trimlevel]').change(function(){
  var total = 0;
  if($(this).checked==true)) {
    total = total + $(this).val();
  }
  $('#myTotal').html('$' + total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a comprehensive named function which adds up everything that can possibly contribute to your total :

```
function calculate() {
    var total = 0;

    if(document.getElementById('basetrim').checked) {
        total = total + 3550.00;
    } else if(document.getElementById('upgrade').checked) {
        total = total + 2400.00;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('leather').checked) {
        total = total + 180.00;
    }

    // further additions here 
    // further additions here 
    // further additions here 

    $('#myTotal').html('$' + total);
});
```

Then attach that named function as the event handler wherever necessary :

```
$('input[name=trimlevel]').change(calculate);
$('input[name=leather]').change(calculate);
//further attachments of calculate as event handler here
//further attachments of calculate as event handler here
//further attachments of calculate as event handler here
```